# How to Batch Import Collada (.dae) files to Esri MultiPatch format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, batch, multipatch

I was wondering if anyone has come across a tool, or can point to code snippets, for batch importing Collada (.dae) files into a MultiPatch format.  I have found a good "How to", but it is all manual.  Also with this manual process the Collada file is not imported into is exact geospatial location.

Here is the youtube link to the "How to"
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udhm3yxVinc

Comment: Do you have FME or the Data Interoperability Extension?

Comment: I believe I have both, but I know I have Data Interoperability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully used FME in the past to do this type of conversion. I can't remember if there were any other quirks to the translation, but if you've never used it before you would essentially just add the appropriate readers and writers, hook them up and see if it works.

In my case I was converting from Google Earth (KMZ) files, which use COLLADA (.dae) models internally. The KML in the KMZ file is what provides the georeferencing information, and FME reads it automatically. <strike>I believe the [COLLADA specification](http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_5.pdf) provides no place to store georeferencing information, so you will need to address that issue somehow.</strike>
 
This [FME Evangelist](http://evangelism.safe.com/) post talks about the georeferencing issue: [GeoNerds, Breadcrumbs, and 3D Georeferencing](http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist49/)

See also, related question: [Export a Sketchup Model to ArcGIS's Multipatch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/how-can-i-export-a-sketchup-model-to-arcgiss-multipatch)

Comment: Thank you, this is great.  I am having the georeferencing issue with Collada, so I was looking at other options. I will look into FME and give it a test.  As a side note, when I loaded the Collada files manually, ArcScene crashed after 5 or 6 were loaded.  Just a note to other who are looking at doing this.

Comment: Actually turns out the specification does include georeferencing information. See section 5-40, "geographic_location". It may be that it's simply not present in your files.